# What happens when a recurring Akka scheduler's Runnable takes longer than the recurring time?

Tags: java, akka

This is for Java Akka.

Let's say I do a scheduler call:

```
...
FiniteDuration interval = new FiniteDuration(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
actorSystem.scheduler().schedule(delay, interval, action, actorSystem.dispatcher());
```

where `action` is of class `SomeRunnable`:

```
public class SomeRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.sleep(60000);
    }
}
```

So every 30 seconds, the scheduler will run the action, which will sleep for 60 seconds. If I run the code, it seems like the when the first sleep finishes, a second one immediately starts. What exactly is happening here? Why does this happen?

Sorry if this is too vague. Thanks!

Comment: Scheduler is completed its finite cycle duration but it waits to complete its previous thread, therefore immediately after sleep completes next thread starts. But please explain what you want to achieve, you want to run scheduler in every 30 seconds even if previous thread is not completed? or you want to wait for 30 seconds after every thread complete?

Comment: So just to clarify, you're saying that the scheduler will wait until the previous thread finishes execution to start the next one? I want to run the scheduler every 30 seconds, even if the previous thread isn't completed. However, if the previous thread isn't completed, I want to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this by starting another thread and stop previous thread.

```
    final Thread previousthread[]=new Thread[1];
    FiniteDuration interval = new FiniteDuration(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    actorSystem.scheduler().schedule(Duration.Zero(), interval, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("next cycle");
            if(previousthread[0]!=null){
                try{
                previousthread[0].interrupt();
                System.out.println("previous thread stopped");
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        System.out.println("before sleep");
                        Thread.sleep(60000);

                    // put your required code here

                        System.out.println("thread complete");
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            th.start();
            previousthread[0]=th;

        }
    }, actorSystem.dispatcher());
```